# podofo writes unwanted stuff to stderr

Tags: c++, pdf, console, stderr, podofo

I am using this line in my code:

```
PdfMemDocument doc(path);
```

And podofo writes this to stderr:

> <<27598670A0B3314EB669BB62DEB4F7FD>]/Info 126 0 R/Prev 503377/Root 1 0 R/Size 1107/XRefStm 500774>>
>
> <<27598670A0B3314EB669BB62DEB4F7FD>]/Info 126 0 R/Prev 503377/Root 1 0 R/Size 1107/XRefStm 500774>>
>
> <<27598670A0B3314EB669BB62DEB4F7FD>]/Info 126 0 R/Prev 503377/Root 1 0 R/Size 1107/XRefStm 500774>>

I dont want this (debug?) output of podofo. Any ideas how to deactivate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call once [PoDoFo::PDFError::EnableDebug](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/doc/html/classPoDoFo_1_1PdfError.html#a2c8dd680d4fda41c25a208643f910321) static method:

```
PoDoFo::PdfError::EnableDebug(false);
PoDoFo::PdfError::EnableLogging(false);
```

Unfortunately, this method defined in header file, so there will be PoDoFo DLL linking errors on Windows. You can fix this issue by modifying PoDoFo source code: move definitions into CPP file.